# How to get computed variable from any model and controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models: **User** and **Account**.

Account is an company account, it has a `slug` field. Slug is needed to determine which company the user is accessing. In example, route `/account/*company_slug*/deals` means that user trying to get an array of deals of *company_slug* company.

Each entity associated with a company has a field `account_id`. That's why I need to get an of the current account. Where should I do this and how?

In example, I get the middleware `CheckIfAccountAcceptedForUser` with the following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $account = Account::find($request->route()->parameter('account'));

        abort_if(empty($account), 404) ;

        abort_if(DB::table('account_user')
            ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($account) {
                $query->where('account_slug', '=', $account->slug);
                $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
            })
            ->get()
            ->isEmpty(), 403);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

How to set the account_id globally for my application, if route is like `/account/*account*/...`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for.

When you check account in middleware you make a query, after that you should make a new query in controller to take account data. In your situation you make 3 queries instead of 1.

You can check it in your account controller by one query.

Route:

```
Route::get('/account/{slug}/deals', 'AccountsController@deals');
```

Accounts controller:

```
public function deals($slug){
    $account = Account::where('id', Auth::user()->account_id)
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->firstOrFail();

    $deals = Deal::where('account_id', $account->id)->get();

    return view('account.deals', compact('account', 'deals'));
}
```

It will always response 404 error if account with current slug doesn't exist or user can't access this account. Do you really need 403 response?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $account = Account::find($request->route()->parameter('account'));

    abort_if(empty($account), 404) ;

    abort_if(DB::table('account_user')
        ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($account) {
            $query->where('account_slug', '=', $account->slug);
            $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
        })
        ->get()
        ->isEmpty(), 403);

      //For global use in your all view file 
      View::share ( 'account_id', $account->id); 

      // to access account_id in controller
      $request->request->add(['account_id' => $account->id]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

In Controller

```
$account_id = request('account_id');
```